# how to query a database of a graph with sql to find paths of a given criteria for samples

Tags: mysql, sql, graph

If I have a database with two tables:

```
 +---------+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
 | samples | r1 | r2 | r3 | r4 | r5 | class |
 +---------+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
 | s1      |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 | a     |
 | s2      |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 | b     |
 | s3      |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 | a     |
 | s4      |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 | a     |
 +---------+----+----+----+----+----+-------+


 +-------+------+----+
 | edges | from | to |
 +-------+------+----+
 | e1    | r1   | r2 |
 | e2    | r2   | r3 |
 | e3    | r3   | r4 |
 | e4    | r4   | r5 |
 +-------+------+----+
```

How do I write an SQL query to find the samples that have a path of r's that have the value 1 of at least length two, and other queries that are similar? (e.g a path of value 1 of exactly length 2 or have a pattern 1,0,1)

The graph is more complicated in reality and has loops, so it needs to account for this.

```
 Query : What samples have a chain of at least three r's that are one?
 Result: s2

 Query: What samples have a chain of 1,0,1?
 s1,s3,s4
```

In prolog I could write something like :

```
sample_with_chain_at_least_3(S):-
      edge(A,B),edge(B,C),r(S,A,1),r(S,B,1),r(S,C,1).
```

where we would have facts stored for each r(s1,r1,1) etc

But it has been a while since I have touched sql and I cant think how to do this simple query in sql..

Comment: Which table are your questions referring to?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am trying to find the samples that meet the criteria.. so SELECT samples.samples FROM samples... then some joins to join the rs etc...

Comment: I can use mysql or another database.. i would want the query to work in 'standard sql' if there is such a thing..